# Integral of equation where I can't isolate x or y.

Tags: integration

I have the differential equation $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{2y} $$

How do I take $$ \int \! \frac{x}{2y} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: "Multiply by $dx$" and by $2y$ to obtain $2ydy=xdx$. Now integrate both sides.

Comment: Are you actually trying to find the integral you asked for? Or are you just trying to integrate to find y in terms of x? Those are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{2y}$  this is a "Separable" diff eq.

$ 2y dy = x dx$ and integrate both sides.  I know, it feels like you are playing fast and loose with the differential operators.

$\int 2y \,dy = \int x \,dx$

$y^2 = \frac{1}{2} x^2 + c$

$y = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} x^2 + c}$

Comment: Thanks everyone. I always thought we should not treat differential operators as variables. But, for the most part it seems to always work. What reason is there not to treat differential operators as variables?

Answer (score 3):

Then $2y\ dy=x\ dx$

$$\int 2y\ dy=\int x\ dx$$

$$y^2=\frac{1}{2}x^2+c$$

$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}x^2+c}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to write

$$\begin{align}
x&=2y \frac{dy}{dx}\\\\
&=\frac{dy^2}{dx} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Integrate both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $x$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int x\,dx&=\int \frac{dy^2}{dx}\,dx\\\\
&\implies \frac12 x^2=y^2+C
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the solution is the family of curves

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2y^2-x^2=C'}$$